# Why does my APK download overwrite an unrelated apk file that is already installed?

Tags: android, download, apk, overwrite

**Background Information**

- We have several .apk files stored on an internal website.
- For simplicity, I will refer to them as file1.apk -> file3.apk in this post.
- The files are named differently, and have their own respective download links on the site.

**The Problem**

- If a user downloads any one .apk file, it will work fine. However, if they choose to download a second apk file, file2.apk for example, AndroidOS will prompt the user if they want to update the file1.apk file that they installed earlier, rather than installing this .apk as a separate file. How can I get the files to all be stored on the device at any given time?

If any more information is needed, feel free to ask.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the AndroidManifest for all the Apps that are concerned ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout Sure. Will post shortly

Comment: @ArthurAttout Turns out they were being built with the same Application ID which is why they were overwriting each other. Thank you for the help! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do they have the same applicationId?

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't personally build out the .apk files, so let me get that information and I'll reply back with it.

Comment: Turns out they were being built with the same Application ID which is why they were overwriting each other. Thank you for the help! It's fixed now.